# How to display weekly(Mon to Sun) data in php and mysql?

Tags: php, mysql, date, group-by

In php i can get today date/day by using : $today = date('D, Y-m-d');

If today is wednesday 8 july, i want to display data from 6 - 11 July (9, 10 and 11 will be blank). How do I do that?

Now my system is like, today is 8 July, i will display 2 - 8 july, but start on wednesday. Not very like this way. I prefer, start on Monday to sunday, then have previous and next week button.

Comment: do you want to display list of current week days (in format 'D, Y-m-d') ?

Comment: i am not sure. What is the easiest and simplest method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use simple `strtotime()` to easy calculate the date of last monday.

```
$lastMonday = strtotime('last monday');
```

Be sure to check if today is *not* monday, because in that case it will return a date week earlier.

Comment: how about next and previous button thing??

Comment: that's easy as - strtotime('next monday');

Answer (score 0):

```
... WHERE  YEARWEEK( $inputdate ) = YEARWEEK( datefield) ...
```

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_yearweek